# Generate 6 alphanumerics from unique id

Tags: javascript, regex, encode

I'm trying to encode a unique identifier with a 6 alphanumeric code and then be able to revert the code back to it's original identifier number.

So far I've been able to reproduce predictable codes such as 11111a, 111112, 111114 etc. with the following:

```
var characters = "123456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var base = characters.length;

function encode(num){
  var encoded = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    var remainder = (num % base) + i;
    num = Math.floor(num / base);
    encoded = characters[remainder].toString() + encoded;
  }
  console.log(encoded);
}

encode(1);
```

I am not looking for randomness. I will be using a decode function to take what I have encoded and use it to get back the original identifier. Is there way for encode to return a less predictable code?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: If you're "not looking for randomness" then it will, almost by definition, be predictable. Perhaps the question to ask yourself is, why do I need to encode it?